Flask with Google OAuth: TypeError for Token Expiry and Premature Token Execution
I'm implementing Google OAuth in a Flask application and encountering two specific issues related to token handling:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'float': When I attempt to calculate the remaining time before the token expires, I receive this TypeError. It seems to occur when I try to subtract a datetime.datetime object from a float. Here's the code where the error occurs:
Token Executed Too Early: The token seems to be processed prematurely, which leads to issues with the token validation or handling. It appears that the token operations might be executing before the token is fully received or properly initialized, causing unexpected behavior. I'm not sure how to properly delay or time the token processing to avoid this.
Also, at the second problem the constant issue is that time of my laptop is supposely out of touch with the one Google is expecting.
Im using LocalTunnel to publish for testing the programm.
Here is the relevant snippet of my code:
@app.route('/authorize')
def authorize():
    flow = Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
        client_secrets_file,
        scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly', 'openid'])
    flow.redirect_uri = 'https://bima-app.loca.lt/oauth2callback'

    authorization_url, state = flow.authorization_url(
        access_type='offline',
        include_granted_scopes='true')

    session['state'] = state
    print(f"State set in session: {state}")

    return redirect(authorization_url)


@app.route('/oauth2callback')
def oauth2callback():
    if 'state' not in session:
        print("State not found in session")
        return redirect(url_for('error'))

    state = session['state']
    flow = Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
        client_secrets_file,
        scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly', 'openid'],
        state=state)
    flow.redirect_uri = 'https://bima-app.loca.lt/oauth2callback'

    authorization_response = request.url
    code = request.args.get('code')

    if not code:
        print("Authorization code not found in request")
        return redirect(url_for('error'))

    try:
        flow.fetch_token(code=code)
        credentials = flow.credentials

        # Token handling
        server_time = time.time()
        print(f"Server Time: {server_time}")
        print(f"Token Expiration Time: {credentials.expiry}")
        print(f"Token Expires in: {credentials.expiry - server_time} seconds")

        if credentials.id_token:
            id_info = google_id_token.verify_oauth2_token(credentials.id_token, google.auth.transport.requests.Request())
            email = id_info.get('email')
        else:
            print("ID token not found in credentials")
            return redirect(url_for('error'))

        if not email:
            print("Email not found in ID token")
            return redirect(url_for('error'))

        token_filename = f"token_{email}.json"
        with open(token_filename, 'w') as token_file:
            token_file.write(credentials.to_json())
            print(f"Credentials saved to {token_filename}")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error fetching token: {e}")
        return redirect(url_for('error'))

    return redirect(url_for('gmail_1_select'))

Has anyone encountered these issues with TypeError when calculating token expiration time or the token being executed too early in Flask? What would be the best approach to resolve these problems?
I attempted to calculate the time remaining before the token expires by subtracting the current server time (as a float) from the token's expiration time (as a datetime.datetime object). I expected this to give me the remaining time in seconds.
To address the TypeError, I tried converting the datetime.datetime object to a timestamp using .timestamp() and then performed the subtraction, but this led to complications with time zone differences and didn't fully resolve the issue.
Dealing with Premature Token Execution:
I reviewed the order in which the token was processed, suspecting that it might be handled before it's fully initialized or received. I tried placing additional checks to ensure the token was available before processing, but this did not prevent the premature execution.
I also explored delaying the execution of token-related operations until I was certain the token was ready, but couldn't find a reliable way to implement this.

If you do type(time.time()), you'll see it's a float. It looks like credentials.expiry is a datetime object. Since you seem to want the time  difference in seconds, try calling timestamp() on credentials.expiry . It will give you a float and then you can subtract time.time() from it.
